# Substitute for ListViewin WinForm

Tags: winforms, listview, devexpress

I have to create two column table with static information something like legend. But I can not use ListView, I can not use DataGridView too, I need to use devExpress component for it. Can someone suggest simple solution?

Answer (score 0):

The very simple solution is to create a DataTable, add two columns to it, and add rows with appropriate data. Bind this DataTable to the GridControl.DataSource property.

The DevExpress XtraGrid works in bound mode only. That is why it is necessary to have the DataTable.